# Threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I am trying to have my main thread spawn off a new thread and, after some time, raise the interrupt flag. When it does so, the spawned thread should see that flag and terminate itself.

The main thread looks something like this:

```
final Thread t = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        f();
    }
};
t.start();
try
{
    t.join(time);
    t.interrupt();
    if(t.isAlive())
    {
        t.join(allowance);
        if(t.isAlive())
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.err.println("f did not terminate in the alloted time");
}
```

And the spawned thread has a bunch of the following scattered throughout its code:

```
if(Thread.interrupted()) return;
```

When I am in debug mode, everything works perfectly. The interrupt flag is raised by the main thread and is caught by the spawned thread. However, in regular run mode the spawned thread doesn't seem to receive the interrupt flag, no matter how long I set the allowance.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Note: I am using Ubuntu and I am all-together new to anything Linux. Can the problem be with the OS? I have not tested the code on any other OS.

Comment: Is the 'f did not terminate in the alloted time' message being printed?

Comment: f is a function designed to run forever if given the opportunity. So, allowance is the amount of time for f to catch the interrupt and exit. Also, the message is printed when the allowance time is up.

Comment: if your function is a while(true) you should change the condition in verifying if the thread is interrupted

Comment: It looks as though the Thread.interrupted() call is not being reached in f(). Can you show us any more of f()? Is there any way f() could block due to a race condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you consider using an ExecutorService which is designed to do this sort of thing and could help you in other ways.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Future<ResultType> future = service.submit(new Callable<ResultType() {
   public ResultType call() throws Exception {
      // do soemthing
      return (ResultType) ...;
   }
);
// do anything you like until you need to result.
try {
   ResultType result = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (TimeoutException timedOut) {
  // handle exception
  // cancel the task, interrupting if still running.
  result.cancel(true);
} catch (ExecutionException taskThrewAnException) {
  // handle exception
}
// when you have finished with the service, which is reusable.
service.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are my guesses:

- When main thread calls `t.interrupt();` the t thread has already finished execution.
- When main thread calls `t.interrupt();` in the t thread there are no more calls to check `interrupted()` flag.
- You get the exception as a result of running the code? Do you get the exception you throw in your code after "allowance" time or you got some other like `ThreadInterruptedException` or similar? Try writing the message of the caught exception...

Comment: * If t finished before the interrupt, then the t.isAlive check will succeed and no error would be thrown.
* The function f is, for all purposes, a while(true) loop that checks for the interrupt in every iteration. Also, each iteration takes considerably less time than the allowance variable provides.
* The exception caught is the one I throw.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the Thread.interrupted() call is not being reached in f().

The different behaviour you are seeing in Debug and Run modes is likely to be due to a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have nested checks of Thread.interrupted()? That method clears the interrupted flag, so the second call returns false. You could use isInterrupted() instead.