# Mechanism of multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

When we call the `#start()` method of the thread, it calls the `#run()` method. But after the invocation of `#start()`, the control returns to the `#main()` method (Or where the thread was created).

Why does this happen? Why doesn't the control jump to the `#run()` method?

Comment: Provide code please if you have it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threading in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871968/threading-in-java)

Comment: The 'control' is just a single thread. When you call start(), a new thread is created, this new thread calls run(), but you are still following the original thread.

Comment: `t.start()` does _not_ call `t.run()`.  It creates a new _thread_, it sets up the new thread to call `t.run()`, it enables the new thread to run, and then it returns to the caller.  There is no guarantee as to whether it will return to the caller before or after the new thread has entered `t.run()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the point of multithreading.

The new thread starts executing its code (from the `run` method) and the main one also continues executing its code, so that code is being executed in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It did help until the second answer showed up. Could you help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, know that a **process** is a just a program in execution.

Every process has at least one **thread**, a unit of execution, which is the main thread. Threads run in parallel to one another.

When you fire off a new thread, the current thread from which you fired it off is still running (until it ends, of course). Now, you have 2 threads running in parallel.

When debugging in an IDE like Eclipse, you are following a specific thread, the main one, usually. So your step-through process in debugging will not follow the execution path of your new thread. It will simply continue on with whatever code comes after you create a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know for sure if it will return to the method where start() was called, or if it will go immediately into the new thread.  Java thread execution is hard to predict.  It may go into the new thread for a bit, then stop and go back to the main thread, then finish the new thread, then go back to the main thread, etc.  The point is, there are two now parallel sets of instructions to be executed, but since the JVM doesn't really execute them in parallel but one at a time, the JVM will execute them in whatever order it determines.